# VB.NET strange IF statement behavior, always else

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, clr, nullable

I've tried these two blocks but it returns the same value. I do not describe more, I simply just show the code:

```
    Dim f As Nullable(Of Integer)
    If f = 1 Then
        Console.WriteLine("Equal")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Not Equal")
    End If
```

It prompts me "Not Equal"

I just add a NOT and I excpect to get the NOT answer, but I got the same as above!!!

```
    Dim f As Nullable(Of Integer)
    If Not f = 1 Then
        Console.WriteLine("Equal")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Not Equal")
    End If
```

It works in C# correctly...

Comment: A minor point: `Not f = 1` is `(Not f) = 1` not `Not (f = 1)`, but they're both still `Nothing`.

Comment: I found the VB.Net so dirty. why people still using it ? how about C#,python,Lua,ruby?

Comment: Some people are "still using it" because they never drank the C# cool-aid, but did drink the VB/VB.NET cool-aid! I've built a career on VB/VB.NET. I've learned enough C# to convert it back to VB.NET, but will prefer to not use it where possible.

Comment: ok, so i must to ask again: why some people never drank the c# cool-aid?

Comment: This is now getting to be ideal for chat (but I'm working at the moment and don't have time). In my case I just didn't need to: VB.NET was a significant change but within my abilities. I understand others preferred to change languages when changing frameworks, but I didn't need to.

Comment: Also BTW I believe the IDE experience for VB.NET is still superior to C# (but I haven't used C# recently enough to know for sure).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR: It works correctly according to the behaviour which is specified for VB, which isn't the same behaviour specified for C#.

The comparison "f = 1" yields a `Nullable(Of Boolean)` in VB. The result of comparing any value with Nothing is Nothing, and neither Nothing nor "Not Nothing" is "True", so you'll always end up in the Else clause.

See the [MSDN page for nullable value types in VB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx) for more details. In particular, if you look for "Comparing Nullable Types" you'll find an example (with explanation) which is very similar to your situation. In particular:

> When the value of a Boolean variable or expression is Nothing, it is neither true nor false.

Comment: It seems a boolean expression may be evaluates as (True or False Or Nothing). Three states for a boolean expression? but the VB's IF keyword just has Two states: Then Or Else ?

Comment: @pylover: It's actually that there are three states for a `Nullable(Of Boolean)` - MSDN isn't clear on that point, unfortunately. But yes, the "If" body will only be executed if the value is True, and the "Else" body will be executed if the value is False or Nothing.

Comment: i will test this situation in IronPython and F#